# Unable to show .xlsx formate in UIDocumentInteractionController / UIWebView

Tags: ios, excel, swift, uiwebview, xlsx

I have been trying to download different documents from server to my swift App and show in `UIDocumentInteractionController`. CSV formats are successfully downloaded and shown in `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

.xlsx formats are downloaded but not recognised by `UIDocumentInteractionController`/ `UIVewbView`.

How can I show a `.xlsx` file in  `UIDocumentInteractionController` in swift

Answer (score 1):

After you've downloaded the file you can use [CoreXLSX](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/CoreXLSX)  library to parse it. The library can be integrated either with [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) or [Swift
Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/). After that you can use it like this:

```
import CoreXLSX

guard let file = XLSXFile(filepath: "./file.xlsx") else {
  fatalError("XLSX file corrupted or does not exist")
}

for path in try file.parseWorksheetPaths() {
  let ws = try file.parseWorksheet(at: path)
  for row in ws.sheetData.rows {
    for c in row.cells {
      print(c)
    }
  }
}
```

This will print every cell in a given Excel file, but you can also filter cells and columns by their references if needed.